# ElasticSearch Canvas - dropdown not working

Tags: elasticsearch, canvas, kibana, elastic-stack

How to add data source properly so that I can get the values in my drop down, it was easy in Kibana but not sure how to do the same in Canvas.

I added the data source from the elastic index but it is not working, on value is coming into the dropdown.

Please let me know if someone has done this.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, I must admit since Canvas is still in beta, it works not perfectly. However, I was able to achieve a drop down filter selection quite easy.

Steps to do:

1. Add element -> Dropdown filter
2. Go to Data and click Change your data source
3. Select index, paste a Lucene query (I used `*:*` to just match everything, select a Sort field - `@timestamp` in my case)
4. Select the field you want to sort by - I used `field1.keyword`
5. Don’t forget to click **SAVE** (otherwise it will be erased, when you will click onto Display tab)
6. Go to Display tab, and type in both values column and filter column your field - e.g. `field1.keyword`. Don’t forget to click **Set** as well

What I faced as a problem for sure - you should always select for filter column - `.keyword` type, otherwise Canvas isn’t able to filter it and will show you empty results.

I also wasn’t able to make it working on multivalue fields, not sure if it’s intended to work only on single value fields or not.